# A cross-platform way to share a USB device over a network?

Tags: linux, windows, networking, usb

Our local Hackerspace has this obscure 3D printer that only has Windows drivers. We'd like to avoid running a Windows computer 24 hours a day, but having it plugged in to a Raspberry Pi would be OK. Is there a way to expose a USB device connected to Linux computer via network so that a Windows computer could operate on it as if it was connected directly?

Answer (score 5):

Linux has [usbip](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/USB/IP) built in, and there seems to be a [Windows port](https://github.com/cezanne/usbip-win) of the `vhci` driver for USB-IP client systems.

(Note that this is *not the same* usbip-win project as the other [usbipd-win](https://github.com/dorssel/usbipd-win) project suggested by Microsoft for WSL – that one only implements the "server" side but lacks vhci and cannot attach as a client. They do use the same protocol however.)

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to run Windows in a virtual machine, and to pass a USB device through to it from the physical host.  This avoids having to dedicate a machine / hardware to Windows (the VM can be shut down or paused to conserve resources)

With sufficiently clever permissions, you can probably share control of that virtual machine over the network per this answer (though note the lack of significant security content in this answer):

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/432532/how-to-use-qemu-remotely

Answer (score 1):

If you are open to NOT use a RaspBerry PI and use a ready-made solution:

There exist networked USB hubs. A small device with 1 or more USB ports and a RJ45. Accompanying software is installed on a Windows PC to connect to the hub and have it appear to windows as if it is a USB hub directly attached to the PC.

They are mostly used for cluster environments where a VM (that needs a USB key or USB license dongle) can be moved between several physical nodes. You don't want to have to move the USB device between the physical nodes when you move the VM.

These networked USB hubs work perfectly fine for this application too.

A very well known brand of these is AnywhereUSB.
(I'm not affiliated with them, just a happy customer of their products.)

Answer (score 0):

I think it will be convenient to use with special software. To share a USB device over the network, you need to connect the printer to your Raspberry, the Raspberry needs to have Internet access, and then you can share the printer using Flexihub, which allows you to share a USB device to any computer (Mac or Windows).
https://www.flexihub.com/usb-over-ip-raspberry-pi/